# How to run async calls as sync

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, xamarin, wkwebview

I am new to C# & Xamarin. I feel there would be some quick solution to achieve this, but I already consumed a day to find one. Please give me a hint so I can proceed in the right direction.

The method is to Resize a Window after getting Height & Width. The issue is the `GetWidth()` and `GetHeight()` runs on async mode while the main thread sets the `Window.SetFrame(...)`, hence I am not able to resize the window.

One solution I think is of cascading and setting the Window frame in the innermost block.

```
private void ResizeWindow() 
{
    _webView.EvaluateJavaScript("document.readyState",
                                    (complete, error) =>
        {
            if (complete != null)
            {
                GetHeight();
                GetWidth();

                CGRect windowRect = Window.Frame;
                windowRect.Size = new CGSize(_width, _height);
                Window.SetFrame(windowRect,true);
        }
    });
}

    private void GetWidth()
    {

        _webView.EvaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollWidth",
                                    (scrollWidth, wError) =>
        {
            if (scrollWidth != null && nfloat.TryParse(scrollWidth.ToString(), out nfloat value))
            {
                _width = value;
            }
        });

    }

    private void GetHeight()
    {
        _webView.EvaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight",
                                   (scrollHeight, hError) =>
        {
            if (scrollHeight != null && nfloat.TryParse(scrollHeight.ToString(), out nfloat value))
            {
                _height = value;
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Xamarin.iOS` already has a `TaskCompletionSource`-based wrapper for `WKWebView.EvaluateJavaScript`.

So you can just `await` the call to `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` for the `NSValue`-based result and then convert it to a C# value type.

Since I know that javascript being run returns a number, I can cast the `NSObject` return (that actually is an `NSValue`) to a `NSNumber` and obtain a C# `long` from it.

#### Example:

```
var result = await webview.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.body.scrollWidth");
var width = (result as NSNumber).Int64Value;
result = await webview.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.body.scrollHeight");
var height = (result as NSNumber).Int64Value;
```

Comment: I am not sure if the above works in iOS, but it did not work for OSX. I ended up invoking a nested call.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Strange, I have that code in Store apps.... you can look at the source code, it is just a TaskCompletionSource wrapper.